# How should negative time work?

Tags: python, time, python-3.x, negative-number

I'm trying to create a `Time` -class which can handle times of format `hh:mm:ss`.
This is what I have:

```
class Time(object):

    def __init__(self, h=0, m=0, s=0):
        #private
        self.__hours = 0
        self.__minutes = 0
        self.__seconds = 0

        #public
        self.hours = h
        self.minutes = m
        self.seconds = s

    @property
    def hours(self):
        return self.__hours

    @hours.setter
    def hours(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.__hours = value

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        return self.__minutes

    @minutes.setter
    def minutes(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.hours += int(value / 60)
        self.__minutes = value % 60

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        return self.__seconds

    @seconds.setter
    def seconds(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.minutes += int(value / 60)
        self.__seconds = value % 60
```

I'm having problems with negative time values.
What I do is check if the time value (e.g. `minutes`) is being set to negative and raise a `ValueError` if it is.
But the thing is, I would like to work with negative time formats too, I'm just not sure how.

How should negative time values behave?
Are they even possible to achieve with my setters?
I really can't even get started, I don't need you to code it for me, but atleast give some tips and explain how negative time works.

Comment: There is **no** point in setting `self.hours`, etc, as the `@property` descriptors with the same name will be used instead *anyway*.

Comment: I think you are confusing a time *delta* with an absolute time. This is a class modeling absolute time, a time of day. A time delta models relative time, and that can be negative. Take a good look at the `datetime` module.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 concepts to time:

- a moment in time (instant)
- a length between two instants (timespan or time delta).

We measure timespan in seconds and multiple of seconds.

A moment of time is described using the same unit, understood as a timespan between some reference time (like 0 BC, or Unix epoch). (The units are more complex though - instead of regular multiples of seconds, we use calendars that assign nice names like "July 16th" to particular moments in time).

---

So:

- Timespan or can certainly be negative (as a whole)
- An instant can be negative too, because there's a timespan inside (like year -3000 BC), but the actual formats don't have negative coefficients (it makes no sense to say "14:-3" or "June -5th").

---

So:

- setting `minutes` to negative on an instant, should be a `ValueError`,
- there could be a method `.later(minutes=10)` that would be equivalent to `.earlier(minutes=-10)`.